# iOS SWIFT - CollectionView particular cell expanding via touch

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have Collection view with horisontal flow, cells are heigh as sceen and width screen/4

So i want to add something like an animated transition so when you trying to expand the cell with two fingers this cell will expand its width until fingers reaches the sides of device, and as well some other stuff will animated as fingers are mooving.

So how can i track the fingers moove to call func in my vc with collection view and operate sizes of components and a cell. As well the expanding one particular cell width in cv so other cells will move away is a little trick to me.

Thanks for any help))

Answer (score 1):

You can use the UIPinchGestureRecognizer to handle zoom using two fingers. By reading the zoom scale value of the view you can change the height and width of the cell then reload the cell.

```
 UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGestureRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinchWithGestureRecognizer:)];
[cell addGestureRecognizer:pinchGestureRecognizer];
```

Swift:

```
var pinchGestureRecognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handlePinchWithGestureRecognizer:"))
cell.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGestureRecognizer)
```

Read the zoom scale value and write your transform stuff here :

```
-(void)handlePinchWithGestureRecognizer:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchGestureRecognizer{
    self.cell.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.testView.transform, pinchGestureRecognizer.scale, pinchGestureRecognizer.scale);
}
```

Swift:

```
func handlePinchWithGestureRecognizer(sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer)
{
    sender.view!.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(sender.view!.transform,
    sender.scale, sender.scale)
}
```

You can refer this also : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ZoomZoom/ZoomZoom.html

Comment: Tryed this method, all works good but the only thing is missing that while trcking the fingers and cell side could go far from ech other, is there any wat to track exact posisition of fingers and set it to cell side so it will be more acurate on all devices? i can do all the calculations or other stuff, i just need something like the sender's finger position on screen. Anyway Thanks Alot for help)))

Answer (score 0):

I would have loved to add this as a comment but I need 50 reputation to do it so be merciful with the down votes :P

You need to use `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`, `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`, and `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`.

You make an animated transition that uses the UICollectionViewCell's frame with respect to the ViewController, so you have to use the convertRect method with respect to the ViewController.view

The animated transition should add a screenshot of the NewViewController with the result of the convertRect method as its starting frame. Then the animation will be from the starting frame to the final frame of the NewViewController.

Test the animation and check if it has the desired result. Then implement 
the `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` and tie it to a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`. I'd suggest adding the pinch gesture to each cell and then creating a delegate for cell, and set the `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` as the delegate for it that implements a function `func userDidUsePinchGesture(gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer)`. In that function you can calculate the percentage of the completion of the transition.

I'm sorry if this wall of text is a bit intimidating, and I hope that this helps you out. If you haven't implemented `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`, `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`, and `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` before I suggest that you check out this tutorial [Creating Custom UIViewController Transitions](https://www.raywenderlich.com/110536/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions)